# The requested URL /learnPHP2/upload.php was not found on this server

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-`enter code here`scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>file upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Uploadfile <input type="file" name="userfile">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
// Check if the form was submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // Check if file was uploaded without errors
    if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

            // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
            $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

                // Verify MYME type of the file
                if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
                    // Check whether file exists before uploading it
                    if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])){
                        echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " is already exists.";
                } else{
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
                    echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
                } 
            } else{
                echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your `enter code here`file. Please try again."; 
            }
        } else{
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to properly format your code and then actually ask a question. Voting to close as-is.

Comment: No idea how you managed to paste code and get that mess

Comment: Not sure what this code is, and if it is `/learnPHP2/upload.php` then I am not sure what it is supposed to tell us

Comment: i have put a folder on the learnPHP2 folder but it won't work

Comment: thanks a lot guys finally am able to i am so happy asanteni sana